# SONM ICO token limit definition

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ico

What is it and why is it written like that. I check pre-sale contract and it was defined in integer.

> uint constant TOKEN_LIMIT = 444 * 1e6 * 1e18;

Specifically that part: 1e6 * 1e18

I really didn't get it and I tried to google it but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soldity can't handle floating point numbers so it must store decimals in integer form.

The `1e<n>` notation basically means "1 followed by *n* number of zeros". So 1e2 is equal to 100 and 1e4 is equal to 10000, and so on.

The expression `444 * 1e6 * 1e18` then means:

`444`

`1e6` = `1000000` (6 zeros)

`1e18` = `1000000000000000000` (18 zeros)

so `TOKEN_LIMIT = 444 × 1000000 × 1000000000000000000`

There are `444,000,000` total tokens (444 × 1e6), but taking account decimal places (the [SOMN](https://etherscan.io/token/0x983f6d60db79ea8ca4eb9968c6aff8cfa04b3c63) token supports up to 18 decimal places) it then becomes (444,000,000 × 1e18).

TLDR; 1eN is exponential notation, to better represent the number of zeros. Solidity only supports [fixed-point](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#fixed-point-numbers) numbers.